# How to get Collapsing + and - symbols in Razor view Editor in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, visual-studio-2012

I am using VS2012 with MVC3, Razor and C#.

Bit confused here. My Razor view does not seem to be showing the Visual Studio nesting "+" and "-" symbols. I see this in other cshtml Views around HTML blocks like , but I want to also see them around Razor {} blocks, in particular to help me work out whether there is a {} mismatch.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT. The more I think of it this is a question about setting up Visual Studion. The symbols are a feature of the editor in the left margin. When one clicks on a "-" symbols the code block collapses, and I would like this to be around code blocks denoted by {}.

EDIT: It seems that CTRL-M,CTRL-H is an approach, and when you do this the "+" and "-" stay there. However you cannot collapse a block and then collapse an outer block around this inner block. It seems one can only collapse one block at at a time.

Comment: Can you provide some code for understanding?

Answer (score 10):

have you tried clicking Edit->Outling->Start automatic outlining?

Just tried it on one of my views and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried this and it works fine with HTML code blocks, but not Razor code blocks surrounded by {}.

Comment: Shortcut key for the html only method is CTRL+M, L, this will toggle the outlining which is the same as this answer.

Comment: I think it maybe but you will have to dig around the formatting of tags.

Comment: assuming your razor blocks are inside tags?

Comment: I have found a C# Outliner extension , see: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc07ec7e-abfa-425f-bb65-2411a260b926 which seems to work fine except in this one Razor file. When I open the file I see the symbols then they disappear. So I guess there is too much nesting or something else is wrong that is upsetting the outliner.