# How to enable collapsible outlines for razor pages in VS2022

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor, visual-studio-2022

I've been working on learning and using ASP.NET Core Razor MVC in VS2022 and I finally found something that's really been bothering me. I am unable to collapse the sections of a Razor Page to make it more compact when I'm working on certain section over others.

When I talk about collapsing the sections, I mean the area highlighted in red, as seen here in VS2019. When editing the same file in VS2022, the dotted lines and collapse boxes for each section are not available.

[The file in question in VS2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY2a2.png)

[The file in question in VS2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6aA2.png)

I've done some searching, and so far the only remedy I've found is to enable the 'Legacy Razor Editor' under the HTML options. That does bring the outlining back, but then it causes fake compile errors on my @model calls. The project still compiles and runs, but I know it is possible to get the outlining without those errors because the series of lessons I'm following has VS2022 setup like that, and unfortunately did not cover whatever setup steps they used to get there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Collapsing + and - symbols in Razor view Editor in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036483/how-to-get-collapsing-and-symbols-in-razor-view-editor-in-mvc3)

Answer (score 0):

In the menu bar, choose:

```
Edit -> Outlining -> Start Automatic Outlining
```

[image]